# Get WMI security setting via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have this code (not just this, but thats the part with the problem)

```
Dim objWMI : Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root")
Dim objSecuritySettings : Set objSecuritySettings = objWMI.Get("__SystemSecurity=@")
Dim objSD : objSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
```

Why am I not getting the objSD ?
If I run the script it returns an error when I try to use `objSD.DACL` or something like that:

> Object not found!

So whats my mistake ?
Something else what´s strange is, if I run it like this:

```
Dim objSD : objSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor objSD
```

It works on Win7 .... but not on server 2003 or 2012.
EDIT:
I tested it on WinServer 2008 and it works perfectly ( like on Win7) .... so why not on 03 and 12 ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't document the behaviour competently here (google for `msdn "Scripting Security Descriptors - Microsoft"`, download the first `DOC` found):

```
option explicit
Dim iSD, intRet
Dim objWMI              : Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root")
Dim objSecuritySettings : Set objSecuritySettings = objWMI.Get("__SystemSecurity=@")
Dim objSD               :          objSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
Dim objSDa              : intRet = objSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSDa)
Dim objSDx              : objSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor objSDx
Wscript.Echo "objSecuritySettings" _
  , VarType(objSecuritySettings), TypeName(objSecuritySettings) _
  , vbNewLine, "objSD ", VarType(objSD) , TypeName(objSD) _
  , vbNewLine, "objSDa", VarType(objSDa), TypeName(objSDa), intRet  _
  , vbNewLine, "objSDx", VarType(objSDx), TypeName(objSDx)
```

**Output**

```
==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\31512037.vbs
objSecuritySettings 9 SWbemObjectEx
 objSD  0 Empty
 objSDa 9 SWbemObjectEx 0
 objSDx 9 SWbemObjectEx

==>
```